# Нужна ли запятая перед "что" в данном случае? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

*Если используется Internet Explorer 11: необходимо убедиться что включена запись.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, запятая **нужна**: *"что"* начинает придаточное. А вот перед *"в данном случае"* запятая была лишней, убрал её.